# Вызов subscribe из сервиса в Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2

Я в сервисе делаю общую функцию (для всех компонентов) для запроса к серверу. Для обработки ошибок на сервере и в самом ответе сразу вызываю subscribe. Как можно дальше в компоненте получить response? Повторно вызывать subscribe (getData().subscribe..) не получается. Сохранять response в локальные переменные и отдельно вызывать?

```
  getData(){
   return this.http.get(url)
      .subscribe(response => {
        return response;
      }, error => {
        return error;
      });
```

Comment: А зачем вы вызываете `subscribe`? Обработку ошибок можно через `catch` сделать.

Comment: Мне нужно в сервисе обработать и общие ощибки сервера и сам ответ ( битый json, или запрос к несуществующему заказу например). В catch сам ответ вроде не попадает.

Comment: Тогда для этого `map` используйте.

Comment: map для обработки всех ошибок?

Comment: `map` будет вызываться перед тем, как придет ответ в `subscribe`(это если коротко и грубо). Поэтому там вы вполне можете сделать обработку ошибок, преобразование данных, сделать `throw` в конце концов.

Comment: А как ошибки можно отфильтровать из map. Они туда попадают?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под ошибками, уточните пожалуйста)

Comment: Ошибки = неправильный ответ сервера (битый json), обращение к серверу за несуществующими данными или вообще отсутствие ответа. Я понимаю, что должен быть какой-то код ответа сервера типа error.status чтобы их все обработать

Comment: Вы разные типы ошибок смешали. Есть битый json, есть не существующие записи, есть не существующий ресурс(404), есть сервер вообще упал. Это разные типы ошибок и обрабатываться они будут по разному. Посмотрите мой ответ.

Comment: да, спасибо, большое, я Ваш ответ видел. Я понимаю, что ошибки разные. Просто по каким признакам их из map идентифицировать, чтобы обработать

Comment: В map попадет ответ, когда сервер ответит `200 - OK`. А там уже ваши требования к ответу можете проверять. В остальных случаях и в случае исключения в `map` будет вызван `catch`.

Comment: Я думаю вы найдёте ответ на свой вопрос [здесь](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses). Основная идея, использовать ```interceptor```'ы, которые позволяют, перехватывать запросы и анализировать ответы от сервера и собственно принимать решение о валидности ответа до передачи данных непосредственно в место их потребления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример запроса в сервисе:

```
getUsersList() {
    const url = 'http://test.ru/api/users/'; // url запроса
    return this.http.get(url)
    .map(
      ( res ) => {
        return res; // можно что то сделать с ответом перед подпиской из компонента
    });
  }
```

Делаем переменную dataResponse в сервисе:

```
 import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'; 
 ... // переходим в класс
 public dataResponse = new Subject<any>();
```

Затем вызов из того же сервиса:

```
getResult() { 
 this.getUsersList().subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log(data); // список пользователей
        this.dataResponse.next(data);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error); // сервер вернул ошибку
        // сделать что угодно.
       }
 );
}
```

Что бы избежать двойного получения данных из сервиса и компонента просто нужно в компоненте подписаться на dataResponse нашего сервиса.

```
this.ourService.dataResponse.subscribe(
  (data) => {
      // data -  Полученные данные.
  }
)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, просто мне из сервиса нужно все ошибки обработать и сервера и возвращенного json

Comment: Если что пиши, по Angular, подскажу что смогу:)

Comment: И не слушай комментаторов выше,  ***в map ошибки не попадают!*** они уходят сразу в error и ты их можешь обработать прямо с компонента.

Comment: из компонента я могу обработать, мне нужно обработать в сервисе, а в компоненте дальше обрабатывать repsponce

Comment: @Zicrael фишка в том, что он не хочет их прямо в компоненте обрабатывать. И где написано, что в `map` ошибки попадают?))

Comment: А где написано что он хочет обработать ошибку прямо в сервисе?)

Comment: @Zicrael Не явно написано в вопросе. И довольно явно в комментарии *"Мне нужно в сервисе обработать и общие ощибки сервера и сам ответ ( битый json, или запрос к несуществующему заказу например)."*

Comment: Да, у меня задача все ошибки обработать в сервисе(

Comment: Ну вы ребята даёте, а кто вам мешает подписаться прямо с сервиса но не в этом же методе?) Обновляю код в ответе:)

Comment: @Alexeev обновил ответ, лучшим решением без костылей будет использование Subject.

Comment: @ Zicrael спасибо большое, сейчас вернусь с собрания гляну

Comment: Обязательно почитай за Subject и BehaviorSubject, это очень полезные вещи для общения между компонентами, сервисами , и без этого рано или поздно никак.

Comment: @ Zicrael да, через Subject работатет так как нужно! Спасибо!!

Comment: Обращайся если что, буду рад поделиться опытом:)

Comment: Куда можно написать. если что?)

Comment: 13ccdd@gmail.com

Comment: Понял, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать сколько хотите `map`, `filter` - они будут вызваны до `subscribe`. Они будут вызываны, если сервер вернул статус `200-OK`. В них вы можете сделать проверку на валидность `JSON`, проверить ответ еще как-то согласно вашей логике.

В `catch` попадут ошибки, связанные с недоступностью ресурса (404, 500, 503) или если было какое-то исключение в `map`.

```
getData(){
   return this.http.get(url)
      .map(response => { // Здесь делаете преобразования
        return response;
      })
      .map(response => { // Здесь делаете проверки
        if(response==null) 
           throw new Error("response is null");
        return response;
      })
      .catch(error=> {
        return response;
      });
```

Потом где-то в компонентах.

```
getData().subscribe(resp=>{});
```